# saml2aws --download-browser-driver recurring failure

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, saml, idp

I've been using saml2aws for a while now, but recently, it broke for me.
Now, when I run the command listed bellow, I get the following error:

```
$ saml2aws login --force --download-browser-driver
Using IdP Account default to access Browser https://aws-account-address/
To use saved password just hit enter.
? Username me@me.com
? Password **************

Authenticating as me@me.com ...
Downloading driver to /Users/me/Library/Caches/ms-playwright-go/1.20.0-beta-1647057403000
Downloaded driver successfully

/Users/me/Library/Caches/ms-playwright-go/1.20.0-beta-1647057403000/package/lib/cli/cli.js:263
    require(playwrightTestPackagePath).addTestCommand(_commander.program);
                                       ^

TypeError: require(...).addTestCommand is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/Library/Caches/ms-playwright-go/1.20.0-beta-1647057403000/package/lib/cli/cli.js:263:40)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
Error authenticating to IdP.: could not install driver: could not install browsers: could not install browsers: exit status 1
```

I removed the sensitive bits, and I've confirmed that I'm using the right web address and credentials and such for the AWS authentication.

I have tried fully removing and redownloading saml2aws, clearing my node cache, uninstalling node and go, and clearing out the Cache folder that the process is downloading Playwright to.

When I take a look at the  /Users/me/Library/Caches/ms-playwright folder, it's empty. I assume that's where we expect the browsers to go.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: As this is an open source project, you should post an issue over https://github.com/Versent/saml2aws - I was also trying to get this up and running recently (using Keycloak as my IdP) but just could not get it working. In the end I ended up using Leapp, so you might want to give that a go if you get no where with the project.

Comment: Thanks! I posted there, but they've yet to get back to me. Figured the community might be able to help out.